# Bluetooth LE event handler quit without exception windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing a Bluetooth LE app on wp8.1 runtime app.
I have registered a value change event to listen when new data are coming.

```
heartRateMeasurementCharacteristic.ValueChanged += heartRateMeasurement_DataChanged;

private void heartRateMeasurement_DataChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
  //do things
}
```

after a while the event is not triggered anymore, and rpgram throw NO exception(I checked runtime, memory etc). How can I debug this? Is that possible the event thread is down leaves without any exception?

under condition that BLE device is keep sending signal.

Comment: How long does it run successfully before notifications cease? How do you know the BLE device is actually continuing to transmit the notify message for the characteristic? Have you tested this device with some other client?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hey thanks for replying, I am having a detect that the  BLE is keeping sending information. The thing I am suspect now that there might be a fail in coding // do something, and lead to the listener thread dead, but the strange thing is that there are no exception throw, which give me no hint what is going on in behind.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but the answer is to set heartRateMeasurementCharacteristic as a global variable.